# Symfony Deprecated : Return type of Knp

Tags: symfony, deprecated, production-environment, knppaginator

When switching to prod mode in .env (with DEBUG=0), I have this error :

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0MAM.png)

I can't neither solve it nor remove it. I'm in version 5.3.16 for Symfony, 8.1.3 for php and in composer.json I have: knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "v5.8.0"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is your site working? Looks like these are deprecation notices. Most likely the reason why you are seeing these notices is because of the PHP log level, see [PHP error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: My site is working but is not yet online. But I just found the error I had not set up the logs and so the error was displayed on the screen rather than in the logs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the deprecation notices you see are from the third party KNP bundle you are using. The only true way to make these permanently go away (without any tricks) is for the code to be updated.

You should at least be able to suppress these notices with PHP error_reporting or like you mentioned with logs.

You could fork their repo on [github](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle), fix the code and then create a merge request.

Hope this helps!